# Scientific Notation for Different Units of Charge

Tags: charge, definition, notation, si-units, metrology

Sorry in advance for the basic question, I’m pretty new to physics. I’m doing some electromagnetism homework and so far in class we’ve used only nano and micro coulombs in our force and electric field equations. When writing these equations we use scientific notation: $10^{-9} \mathrm{C}$ for nanocoulombs and $10^{-6} \mathrm{C}$ for microcoulombs. My question is what exponent do I use if the unit is in just coulombs? Thank you, and please tell me if this needs more clarification.

Comment: $1 \mathrm{C} = 10^0 \mathrm{C}$, where $\mathrm{C}$ is the unit Coulomb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prefix names are for powers that are multiples of three as shown below.

The $3.2$ is chosen randomly for the example.

megacoulomb: $3.2\times10^6~\mathrm{C}=3.2~\mathrm{MC}$

kilocoulomb: $3.2\times10^3~\mathrm{C}=3.2~\mathrm{kC}$

Coulomb: $3.2\times10^0~\mathrm{C} = 3.2~\mathrm{C}$

millicoulomb: $3.2\times10^{-3}~\mathrm{C}=3.2~\mathrm{mC}$

microcoulomb: $3.2\times10^{-6}~\mathrm{C}=3.2~\mathrm{µC}$

nanocoulomb: $3.2\times10^{-9}~\mathrm{C}=3.2~\mathrm{nC}$

These are in order, largest to smallest; there are others too that you can look into.

Comment: Slight clarification. The unit is only "Coulomb" but one may add any prefix as one wishes as for example nano (which is a prefix) being $10^{-9}$.

Comment: @ludz good point, will edit to 'prefix'

Comment: @ Chemomechanics , some care was given to the presentation, to make it readable and clear, would be better if the latest edit was undone!

Comment: I edited to apply the NIST/BIPM recommended style regarding unit capitalization and spacing (also consistent with the Springer–Nature and Elsevier style guides). Feel free to revert, but consider the readers who benefit from conventional presentation.

Comment: @ Chemomechanics ok, between us a good compromise has been found, clear and also conventional